# Temperature versus heat for water

Tags: thermodynamics, water, physical-chemistry

What does the kink (abrupt rise and fall) in region of phase change from liquid to vapour state in the following graph indicate? Does it indicate that temperature rise and fall abruptly during phase change (boiling)? I searched about it on internet but can't get any clue!

[image: TEMPERATURE VS HEAT GRAPH OF WATER]

Comment: It means that there is a break in the data along the Heat axis between D and E.  Look at the numbers along the axis.

Comment: Whenever there is a const. value of y for a large no of input values x, this is a standard procedure to clip those data by showing a kink like that. Otherwise you can't fit the graph in a standard size. This has no physics, its a notation.

Comment: Typically one would put a "kink" in the X-axis as well to avoid confusion.  This particular graph appears to have a nonlinear X-axis -- not even logarithmic.  That means the author needs to be dope-slapped.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Graph of heating of ice]

Look at how long the horizontal scale is from 0 to 771,000.

Now compare that length to the distance between 771,000 to 3,070,000.

ie 3,070,000 - 771,000 = 2,299,000

You'll find that 2,299,000/771,000 = 2.98.

The second distance on the graph is not 2.98 times longer than the first; so a big piece is missing and that is what the kink (abrupt rise and fall) in the region of the phase change from liquid to vapour state in the graph indicates. **Not**  temperature is rising and falling abruptly during phase change (boiling).

If you don't put that "kink" in the diagram and redraw it to scale, you will see that a lot more energy has to go in to going from liquid water to steam as compared to going from ice to liquid water.